# Stylus - Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Tags: npm, stylus, error-reporting

When i try to compile .styl to .CSS, i get errors like this:

```
TypeError: css\style.styl:369:1
   365| /*footer*/
   366|         .footer
   367|                 {position: relative; bottom: 0; width: 100%;}
   368|         .footer p {}
   369|
--------^
Cannot read property 'block' of undefined

at Group.block (C:\Users\My Thinkpad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\stylus
\lib\nodes\group.js:48:23)
at Group.clone (C:\Users\My Thinkpad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\stylus
\lib\nodes\group.js:90:21)
at C:\Users\My Thinkpad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\stylus\lib\nodes\bl
ock.js:93:21
at Array.forEach (native)
at Block.clone (C:\Users\My Thinkpad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\stylus
\lib\nodes\block.js:92:14)
at Group.clone (C:\Users\My Thinkpad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\stylus
\lib\nodes\group.js:90:28)
at C:\Users\My Thinkpad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\stylus\lib\nodes\ro
ot.js:65:21
at Array.forEach (native)
at Root.clone (C:\Users\My Thinkpad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\stylus\
lib\nodes\root.js:64:14)
at MemoryCache.set (C:\Users\My Thinkpad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\st
ylus\lib\cache\memory.js:25:21)
```

So it says it couldn't read "block" from my .styl file but it points at the end of file!

What i did:

- I've Carefully checked indents and removed whitespaces.
- I've re-installed Stylus.
- tried unindent like this but no luck:

  .footer

  {position: relative; bottom: 0; width: 100%;}

Specification:

- Win7
- Installed Stylus globally with npm

The question is how can i find what is wrong when it doesn't report anything usefull?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `{position: relative; bottom: 0; width: 100%;}` at the same line as `.footer`. Stylus doesn't parse your code correctly because it thinks that `{position: relative; bottom: 0; width: 100%;}` is a nested selector with interpolation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but It didn't work. I should say apart from naive CSS syntax i have this Stylus syntax part also:
    `.home h2
    align(horizontal);
    z-index: 2; font-size: 1.1em;`
If i unindent this part like what you said, then it gives me this error:
    `expected "indent" , got ";"`
If i don't, it gives me the previous error.

I can put the whole file if it helps. this is my fault or this is a bug?

Comment: You should place `{position: relative; bottom: 0; width: 100%;}` at the same line as `.footer`. See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGdaYL. If you're using CSS syntax you shouldn't indent blocks of code inside `{}` because in this case Stylus will parse it as interpolation.

Comment: Silly me, thanks for explanation, Solved.
What was the `block` it couldn't read?! it doesn't matter anyway.